# How does "Bonus Fish" affect the number of fish I catch?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

When fishing at the Holo House, you the "bonus fish" counter increases by 1 for every 10 fish caught successfully in a row. I initially assumed bonus fish was a direct additive or multiplicative increase to how many fish I catch at once. However, at one point I caught 4 manta rays while my Bonus Fish counter was at 6.

If "Bonus Fish" increases the number of fish I catch, how is that increase calculated?

[image: Bonus Fish at 7]